# ¿Como puedo obtener la ID de Facebook de alguien con Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño código python y necesito saber cómo puedo automatizar el proceso de pasar de la URL de un perfil de Facebook a su ID.

Por ejemplo, el facebook de Sony es "https://facebook.com/Sony" pero el ID es "56232316996"
(https://facebook.com/56232316996) (vía findmyfbid.com).

¿Cómo puedo automatizar este proceso usando el código python?

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: La pregunta está escrita en inglés. El idioma oficial de este sitio es español.

Comment: Ya te fijaste en la API de Facebook?